# Panel component for Vaadin 10 (Flow)

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 10 the Panel component isn't existing in the moment.

In Vaadin 8 Panel is a container with a frame around the content and a caption heading. I need exactly this in Vaadin 10 - how to accomplish? Here an example from the Vaadin 8 docs:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components.html and the directory?

Comment: Yes - "Planned with vaadin-card element. No timeline yet." So it is not clear, when it will come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could easily do this with a `VerticalLayout` (Div for title + Div for content) and CSS. Unfortunately, they didn't make a corresponding component in Vaadin 10. See [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components.html) for an overview of components and their counterparts in Vaadin flow.